# Как сделать, опускание toolbar при скроллинге страницы вниз?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Как сделать, чтобы когда страницу скроллишь вниз тулбар нижний поднимался, а когда вверх сколлишь он опускался бы.(речь идет про toolbar2)

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<include layout="@layout/tollbar_post" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="ru.stopgame.artem.stopgame.utility.ScrollingToolbarBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/views"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/komments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/printing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:linksClickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Код:

```
class ScrollingToolbarBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<Toolbar> {

    public ScrollingToolbarBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, Toolbar child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, Toolbar child, View dependency) {
        if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {

            int distanceToScroll = child.getHeight();

            int bottomToolbarHeight = child.getHeight();//TODO replace this with bottom toolbar height.

            float ratio = dependency.getY() / (float) bottomToolbarHeight;
            child.setTranslationY(-distanceToScroll * ratio);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Опустить toolbar не получается, чтобы он просто поднимался

Comment: `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`?

Comment: @McDaggen добавил в toolbar, и не помогло(